# Applying SameDefinition for SameType on PS

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

can I shorten the following definitions as much as possible?

```
function Get-Info {
    [CmdletBinding()] Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $True)][String]$A,
        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $True)][String]$B,
        [Parameter(Position = 2, Mandatory = $True)][String]$C,
        [Parameter(Position = 3, Mandatory = $True)][String]$D
    )
....
```

**Expected:**

```
function Get-Info {
    [CmdletBinding()] Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $True)][String]$A,$B,$C,$D
    )
....
```

Comment: `Mandatory = $True` can be reduced to just `Mandatory` and `Position` can be inferred if `PositionalBinding` is not `$false`. Thats as short as it will get.

Comment: Maybe but they are necessary for me, for psv2 :) -SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: Adding to Santiago's comment: separate parameters must invariably be declared individually, along with any attributes. As an aside, on a general note: If you need PowerShell v2 support - which is quite unusual these days - please tag your question as such.